# Command browse_website returned: Error: chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255. Auto-GPT

Tags: docker, chromium, autogpt

Getting this error when running Auto-GPT.  It is trying to access chromium from docker.

`$ docker-compose run auto-gpt`

...

```
   SYSTEM:  Command browse_website returned: Error: Message: Service 
   /home/appuser/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/112.0.5615.49/chromedriver 
   unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255
```

Running M1 Mac.  Please help.  Thanks